# SharpDX how to get mouse Position on the gameScreen

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I'm learning SharpDX but I found a problem while learning about the MouseManager class and the Mouse class in the DirectInput.
I don't know how to get the mousePosition which is important to me because of adding buttons to my game.I saw the Documentation but I didn't found any help here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the `RenderForm` to display your game. If that is the case you can just subscribe to mouse events as you would with windows forms:

```
int x;
int y;
// form is RenderForm
form.MouseMove += (sender, args) => {
    x = args.X;
    y = args.Y;
};
```

Comment: I'm using the Game class because Game class contains the Update and Draw methods
@Jens Nolte

Comment: I need to know how to solve this issue with getting the mouse position because I made a simple Tile Map Editor in SharpDX but every function is with KeyBoard because of this Mouse issue :/

Comment: I haven't used the toolkit, but this sample seems to contain everything you need: https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit/blob/master/Source/VisualStudio/ToolkitGame/%24safeclassname%24.cs

Comment: Basically you want to create a new instance of the `MouseManager` during initialization and use the `GetState()`-method during your `Update` to get the mouse data.

Comment: MousePosition from GetState() method returns only Delta position :/

Answer (score 0):

mouse pos in SharpDX is in the range of [0,1]. I have a tile map editor as well.

I need to stabilize it but you can check out the code [here](https://github.com/RadioSpace/Quadratus/tree/master/TileEngine).
(uses DX11 without toolkit)

anyways

just multiply the X,Y values by Width/Height.

don't worry this threw me off as well.

Comment: So what shall I do if I want to make a hover state for buttons ?

Comment: @Rasd is your project hosted somewhere I can take a look. all you need is basic collision detection and a small state manger